# Port forwarding based on time

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up a server where clients connect to a specific port (let's say A) and they are redirected, based on time, to other (local) ports (B and C).
For example, if a client connects to A and it is forwarded to B, when it is time for a port change it should be forwarded to C and, it would be better, without disconnection.
Is it possible?

Comment: On the TCP level the connection breaks if you change the destination port.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--match` module to add some additional criteries to your rules:

```
time match options:
    --datestart time     Start and stop time, to be given in ISO 8601
    --datestop time      (YYYY[-MM[-DD[Thh[:mm[:ss]]]]])
    --timestart time     Start and stop daytime (hh:mm[:ss])
    --timestop time      (between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59)
[!] --monthdays value    List of days on which to match, separated by comma (Possible days: 1 to 31; defaults to all)
[!] --weekdays value     List of weekdays on which to match, sep. by comma (Possible days: Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun or 1 to 7 Defaults to all weekdays.)
    --kerneltz           Work with the kernel timezone instead of UTC
```

see `iptables -m time -h`

**Conclusion**: you can add several forward rules with different times. But tcp sessions will be breaks after destination changes (as [Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging) mentioned above)